# Proving polynomial v.s. is a norm

Tags: normed-spaces

Let $X$ be the vector space containing all polynomials with real coefﬁcients. For every $P ∈ X$, deﬁne $N_1(P) = \sup_{t∈[0,1]} |P(t)|$ and $N(P) = N_1(P) + |P'(1)|$.

I have to prove $N_1$ is a norm on $X$. Then prove $N$ is a norm on $X$.

I'm confused what symbol we use when checking the three conditions of norm definition. For eg, when checking $||...|| \geq 0$, what do we put as the "..."?

Is there a way we can define the set $X$.

Comment: $\|P\|=N(P)$. The question is what is $P_0$.

Comment: edited. and why do we refer to N(P) and not N_1 (P)?

Comment: I assumed that it was a typo. But if not, I wonder what $N(P)$ is for.

Comment: oh sorry, There is further parts to this question so that is what its for. So what do we put inside the || ||?

Comment: Then check all the axioms for $\|P\|=N(P)$ and then check all the axioms for $\|P\|=N_1(P)$.

Answer (score 0):

You have to check that $N(P)\ge 0$ for all $P\in X$.

The set $X$ is described in your first line, it is the set of all real polynomials. Actually its elements can be added and scaled by scalars, so it forms a vector space.

So, let $P$ be any polynomial, and you have to show that $\sup_{t\in [0,1]}|P(t)| \ge 0$. And, actually this is true for any *function* $P$ because of the absolute value, so you don't even need to use the fact that $P$ is a polynomial.

Comment: with your first line, don't u mean $N_1(P) \geq 0$?

Comment: This is what ive done, please check: (i) Clearly $N_1(P)\geq 0$ as you stated. Also let $N_1(P)=0$ then $\sup |P(t)|=0$ which forces $P(t)=0$ for all $t$ so $P=0$. Let $P=0$, then $P(t)=0$, $ \forall t$ so $N_1(P)=\sup |0|=0$. Hence $$N_1(P)=0 \iff P=0$$ (ii) Let $a \in \mathbb R$. Then $$N_1(aP)=\sup |aP(t)|=a \sup |P(t)|= a N_1(P)$$ since $a$ does not depend on $t$. (iii) Let $Q \in X$. Then $$N_1(P+Q)=\sup |P(t)+Q(t)| \leq \sup |P(t)| \sup |Q(t) = N_1(P) + N_1(Q)$$, so $$N_1(P+Q) \leq N_1(P) + N_1(Q)$$. Hence $N_1(P)$ is a norm. Is this OK?

Comment: Please help $$ ${}$

Comment: Yes, exactly...